# how to indent jqgrid table?

Tags: css, jqgrid

How can I have the table in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/yNw3C/) indented, I would like to have white space on the side of the 2 rows and the header, basically I'd like a white margin on the left of everything below "Stackoverflow example".
It would be great if I could do it only with css.

Here is the code:

```
var data = [[48803, "DSK1", "", "02200220", "OPEN"], [48769, "APPR", "", "77733337", "ENTERED"]];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Thingy', 'Blank', 'Number', 'Status'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'id',
        index: 'id',
        width: 60,
        sorttype: "int"},
    {
        name: 'thingy',
        index: 'thingy',
        width: 90,
        sorttype: "date"},
    {
        name: 'blank',
        index: 'blank',
        width: 30},
    {
        name: 'number',
        index: 'number',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float"},
    {
        name: 'status',
        index: 'status',
        width: 80,
        sorttype: "float"}
    ],
    caption: "Stack Overflow Example",
    // ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){alert('double clicked');}
});

var names = ["id", "thingy", "blank", "number", "status"];
var mydata = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    mydata[i] = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
    $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
}

/*
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {onSelectRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){alert('row clicked');}});
*/
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){alert('double clicked');}});
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you need to implement: where exactly you want to have "indented". The text which you posted can be interpreted in different ways. You wrote for example "white space on the side of the 2 rows and the header". Do you means *columns* instead of rows? Or you need to indent only for some *selected rows* of the grid instead of the whole column? Do you want that the size of margin depend on the length of the title (Stackoverflow example) of grid? The code which you included is very far from your final solution. Is the column under the name `"blank"` what you want to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only solution. There is still a challenge for you when resizing columns. As you click and drag to resize, the vertical marker still shows at the original offset.

```
#gbox_grid, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar {
    margin-right: -20px;
}    
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td:first-child {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: inherit;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/meharg/8BkMw/4/

Answer (score 0):

Because this is loaded after the CSS is parsed it will be hard to do it without a little JS if you are picky about the position of your `script` and `style`, here is what works without you needing to worrie about anything. Although i don't think it will work regardless of the style and script position if you want only a CSS solution as the table is generated after it gets parsed anyway.

http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/1534/embedded/result/

I added some comments where i added the code.

Edit, forgot to add the editable fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/1539/